# Kattis "CD" challenge incorrect answer

Tags: java, algorithm

I have been trying to complete [this programming question](https://open.kattis.com/problems/cd) on Kattis,

[image]

I am getting the correct answer in all of my test cases but when I submit it I am getting told I have the wrong answer, If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it, thanks and here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Kattis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        
        while(n != 0 || m!=0)
        {
            boolean[] ar1 = new boolean[1000000];
            int count = 0;
            
            for(int i = 0; i < n+m;i++)
            {
                int num = sc.nextInt();
                
                if(ar1[num])
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    ar1[num] = true;
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println(count);
            n = sc.nextInt();
            m = sc.nextInt();
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem statement says that the input numbers can have values up to a billion.  Did you test your program with numbers like 999,999,999 ?

Comment: Yes, i've just realised that and so I have changed the size of the array to accomodate this, although it now says time limit exceeded?

Comment: I'm a little surprised that it let you create an array that big, but OK.  If the program is taking too long then either you have to find a better algorithm (although it's not easy to beat the one you have, if you can afford the memory) or figure out how to do less work in the existing program.  Did you read the Kattis FAQ about Scanner being slow, and what you can do about that?  You're also doing unnecessary work in your main loop, but that's tiny compared to the Scanner overhead.

Comment: I passed this in C, but a byte array of 1000000000 gives a memory error in Java. There should be a more compact way to store bits or use some sort of xor trick to find the dupe (?).